# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

Tags: laravel-5

I am pretty new to Laravel and I am trying to add the post, create by a user into the database. But when I do so, following error comes:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() 
>   must be an 
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, string given, 
>   called in C:\xampp\htdocs\lar\app\Http\Controllers\PostController.php on line
>   25 and defined

User model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Post Model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User') ;
    }
}
```

PostController:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class postController extends Controller
{
    public function postCreatePost(Request $request){
        // Validation
        $post = new Post();
        $post->$request['body'];
        $request->user()->posts()->save('$post');
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Post Route:

```php
Route::post('/createpost',[
    'uses' => 'PostController@postCreatePost',
    'as'=>'post.create'
]);
```

Form action:

```html
<form action="{{route('post.create')}}" method="post">
```

Please tell me how to fix this.. How to fix this?
Thank you in advance.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class postController extends Controller
{
    public function postCreatePost(Request $request){
        // Validation
        $post = new Post();

        // here you set the body of the post like that
        $post->body = $request->body;

        // here you pass the $post object not as string
        $request->user()->posts()->save($post);
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
}
```

You need to pass the `$post` object as an object to the `save` method. You was doing this: `$user->posts()->save('$post')` when you need to do this: `$user->posts()->save($post)`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you I tried it, but then another error came: QueryException in Connection.php line 761:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'body' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (8, 2016-10-20 10:04:19, 2016-10-20 10:04:19)).

Comment: I added default value :$table->text('body')->default(" "); , but it didn't work.
I don't understand what I did wrong...

Comment: Oh, now I get it... but updated_at and created_at are automatically created by timestamps(), then why does it need a default value? and how to provide it?

Comment: Did you change the line `$post->body = $request->body;`? Somehow your body is not being set.

And yes, Laravel automatic updates your timestamps. If you don't want that, just set `public $timestamps = false;` in your model.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that. Thank you so much :) , but i didn't understand. Why is it not being sat? If you know please can you tell me?

Comment: Did you change and still not working? If you use `$post->$request['body']`, in the end your Eloquent model will try to get an atribute with the same name of the content of the body. You need to use the `=` to set an atribute.